# 802.1x and mab with ip phone and pc beyond it

Tags: hp-procurve, ieee-802.1x, mac-auth-bypass

I have 2 switches . Hp2620 and 2610. I have an ip phone connected to the switch(i use mab to authenticate) and pc(connected to the ip phone) with dot1x. Each work individually bu they dont work together. Can anyone help me with a config example to make this work. Thank you.

Comment: The default is that only one (first seen) MAC address per switch interface for MAB. You need to enable Multi-Authentication Host Mode or Multihost Mode (Cisco supports this, but I do not know about HP).

Comment: Actually i want to make it work like the multi-domain method on cisco. When I plug them individually it works but when i connect the pc to the phone it doesnt.

Comment: I doubt that mode works with HP since it uses CDP to negotiate that with a phone.